# Chart axis increments vb

Tags: vb.net, vba, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to place some reasonable axis increments on my vb .net graph. I have used:

```
    Chart1.Series(0).Points.DataBindXY(Wavelength, Normalised)

    Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.RoundAxisValues()
    Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Minimum = 0
    Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Maximum = 2048
    Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Interval = 100
```

Which plots the graph corresponding to indicies 0 to 2048, in intervals of 100. However as the x axis array starts at 341.1049 and has non integral spacings, the x axis has nasty data labels with many decimal points.

Is there a way of displaying from say 300 to say 10000 with increments of 100?

[Here's my chart, see the increments have many decimals and aren't nicely spaced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktDHC.png)

It is because the AxisX.Maximum and .Interval uses interval spacings of the X axis series and not actual values. Though I can't seem to find any reference of any alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, I understood what you were asking. `Intervall` is not what you are looking for. You need `AxisX.MajorUnit`. Intervalls says after how many points should a label be rendered. For ex. if you set it to 1 you will have a label on your axis for every point in the series.

With `MajorUnit` and `MinorUnit` you control what you mean as Intervall.

Here you have sth that could help you, you can use the `LabelStyleFormat`like this to format your axis labels:

```
With Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX
    .Minimum = 300
    .Maximum = 10000
    .MajorUnit= 100
    '//Here you can format the axis labels
    .LabelStyle.Format = "0.###"
    .Title = "TestTitle"
    .TitleFont = New Font(New FontFamily("Arial"), 9, FontStyle.Bold)
End With
```

This is for the X axis, to change the Y axis just use `Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AsisY`.

Comment: That's a nicer way to write it, thanks. However the .Minimum etc are indices of the plotted array and not actual values, this means that on my x axis I have loads of decimal places and the spacing between values written on the axis is not equal.

I have attached a graph to show this. 

Thanks for the help!

Comment: edited my answer. I didnt understand you right. I hope now it is what you were looking for :) If so vote up, if not hate me a lot:P